# Need advice with design - changing static into normal methods

Tags: php, oop

My whole project is basically divided into two parts:

- core
- helper classes

User creates his custom classes and uses methods from helper classes in there like:

```
\Project\System\Helpers\Class::foo();
```

So every public method in each helper class is declared as static. I've came up with an idea to change this, make all user custom classes inherit one special class:

```
class SingleBeingInheritedClass {
   public function helper($class)
   {
      return new \Project\System\Helpers\$class; // it's just to show the idea
   }
}
```

so that instead of calling static function, user could write:

```
$this->helper('class')->foo();
```

The problem is I use some of these helper classes inside a couple of core classes. And I don't want core classes to inherit anything related to helpers.

In these core classes I also don't want to make the code longer and initialize objects in every method using these helpers.

How should I handle this? Or maybe static methods aren't that bad here?

Comment: You should start using OOP if you're using a plug-in like system. Currently you're not. [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: It's easy to say. What if in some helper class I'd need to call Url::segment() - another helper's method? I could create one big inheritance to handle it with $this (in single line), or I could initialize objects everywhere. In both cases I get some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I also don't want to make the code longer and initialize objects in
>   every method using these helpers.

I you would like to avoid instantiating objects, then you shall stick to static methods. In my projects I use static methods for helpers, for the exact same reason.
These helper classes are then used as 'function libraries'. In this case, class is more like a namespace for the helper functions, not something which gets instantiated.